# Annual median from daily measurements

Tags: r, median

I have a series of day-level animal counts (some days have multiple measurements, some have none) over a course of a year. There's a temporal trend, and the variability depends on the y value (=higher when counts are high). I need to estimate a total annual median with 95% confidence intervals. Of the things I tried: estimate daily median (from a model, which also predicts medians for non-sampled days), then do bootstrapping within each day to get daily 95% CIs (as % of estimated median). Calculate annual median % CIs, and apply to the sum of daily medians to get a yearly % CI. This would have worked, but I have too few samples per day to make the bootstrap defensible.

Should I just resample the data and refit the model to get (say) 1,000 daily estimated medians, then use those to calculate daily 95% CIs?

Simulated data with similar structure to mine:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- 1:365
id <- sample(1:365, 200, replace = TRUE)
y0 <- exp(-1 + 0.1 * x[id] - 0.0004 * x[id]^2)
y <- y0 + rnorm(200, 0, y0/5)
plot(x[id], y)
```

Any advice?

Comment: Possible migration to http://stats.stackexchange.com.